# HTML whitespace issue

Tags: html, ide, phpstorm, whitespace

My web application has started creating nodes for all the whitespace in my html file.

This code:

```html
              <td hidden>
                <input type="text" hidden name="lines[{{$i}}][id]" id="lines[{{$i}}][id]"
                       value="{{$line->id}}">
              </td>
```

is resulting in the td node having 3 children, two texts and the input.

Please see this image:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/E8iYFr9.png]

There I have console.log'd the element. I am not aware of how I have caused this to happen? I am using the PhpStorm IDE. I do not know what terms I would search in google to find an answer either.

edit: it seems to be the indenting. Is the web browser supposed to render indenting?

Thank you,

Comment: @RyanWilson What would I be looking for to fix this? Is my IDE converting the line breaks incorrectly?

Comment: @GlanUK what is up with the `input type="text" hidden`? Are you trying to not display textboxes? Or did you mean to make them `input type="hidden"`

Comment: HTML is not Python, indentation is indistinguishable from regular white-space. The only special rule is that consecutive white-space is collapsed upon rendering.